# How update table with duplicate primary key?

Tags: mysql

I trying to update a table with another table of other database, I the last updated I created a function to save more than one category in one product, so, I when a run the old script to update my table, a constraint error appears. I understand the situation and why that is happenning, but how I allow the update with the table with duplicates data? Is there a way to disable the constraint?

**My query**

```
UPDATE novourbano.oc_product_to_category oc
INNER JOIN erp_product_category erp ON oc.product_id = erp.erp_productid
SET oc.product_id = erp.erp_productid,
oc.category_id = erp.erp_categoryid
WHERE oc.product_id <> 0
```

I try to use that:

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

But still not working. Any suggestion? Thank's in advance!

Comment: Primary keys must always be unique. You can never have two rows in the same table with the same primary key. Switching off constraint checking will not solve this. You have to make sure you don't try to insert a new row with the same primary key as an existing row.

Comment: Well, you can't have a duplicate primary key. That's one of the properties of a primary key. So you would need to generate a new key that isn't different in some way.

Comment: You must be mixing concepts in your mind. Primary keys are one thing, foreign keys are another. Whatever, you're basically asking how to have two houses with the same street address—what for?

Comment: The OpenCart system register two rows with same primary key to oc_product_to_category, I thinking to create a "product_catedory_id" or something like that to divert that constraint error. That can make troubles in future?

Comment: Isn't that a bug either in OpenCart core or in your customisation? Disabling data integrity to let a bug flow doesn't seem a good bet for the future.

Comment: I created a new column auto-increment and set as primary key and the product_id and category_id still get the values, that resolve the problem, there's no bug in my marketplace neither personal system. If you want answer that, go ahead, I do mark the answer like correct.

Comment: If now you allow duplicate product to category combinations, you'll probably allow products being in more than one category as well. Also, I can't help wondering what happens when you edit a product in the backend and assign it to another category—will it edit all rows or just one?

Comment: @Vinicius Rosa, looks like you've just spoiled your table. You've allowed unnecessary duplicates to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table name reflects the table purpose the primary key should be

`PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category_id)`

in order to avoid duplicates like several rows with the same `product_id` and `category_id`.

You can use `IGNORE` for this update:

```
UPDATE IGNORE novourbano.oc_product_to_category oc
INNER JOIN erp_product_category erp ON oc.product_id = erp.erp_productid
SET oc.product_id = erp.erp_productid,
oc.category_id = erp.erp_categoryid
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!